# Android, SeekBar in dialog

Tags: android, dialog, seekbar

I would like to use a dialog with a seekbar in my application.
But I don't really know how to do it because I lack experience with android.

So, when you press a button: a dialog should come up, with a seekbar and the user is able to enter a value and then press OK-button.

The code I have at the moment is the default code by developer.android:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
        .setCancelable(false)
       .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                MyActivity.this.finish();
       }
   })
   .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            dialog.cancel();
       }
   });
AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
```

How should I do to add a `SeekBar`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Maybe you could think of create a custom dialog; it requires more work but it usually works for me ;)
Create a new layout file for your dialog (say, your_dialog.xml):

```
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/your_dialog_root_element"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>

<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/your_dialog_seekbar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
</SeekBar>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/your_dialog_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
</Button>
```

Then, in your activity:

```
Dialog yourDialog = new Dialog(this);
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_dialog, (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.your_dialog_root_element));
yourDialog.setContentView(layout);
```

Thus, you can operate on your element as follows:

```
Button yourDialogButton = (Button)layout.findViewById(R.id.your_dialog_button);
SeekBar yourDialogSeekBar = (SeekBar)layout.findViewById(R.id.your_dialog_seekbar);
// ...
```

and so on, to set listeners for button and seekbar.

EDIT:
The seekbar onchangelistener should be as follows:

```
OnSeekBarChangeListener yourSeekBarListener = new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            //add code here
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            //add code here
    }

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBark, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            //add code here
    }
 };
 yourDialogSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(yourSeekBarListener);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Though i can't set the seekbar onseekbarchangelistner, it gives me an error!

Comment: I've added onseekbarchangelistener stub code at the end of the answer, check it or tell what doesn't work! ;)

Answer (score 10):

I hope this will help you. 
Try this Code...

```
final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this); 

    alert.setTitle("Alert Box"); 
    alert.setMessage("Edit Text"); 

    LinearLayout linear=new LinearLayout(this); 

    linear.setOrientation(1); 
    TextView text=new TextView(this); 
    text.setText("Hello Android"); 
    text.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10); 

    SeekBar seek=new SeekBar(this); 

    linear.addView(seek); 
    linear.addView(text); 

    alert.setView(linear); 



    alert.setPositiveButton("Ok",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
    { 
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id)  
        { 
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "OK Pressed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
            finish(); 
        } 
    }); 

    alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()  
    { 
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id)  
        { 
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cancel Pressed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
            finish(); 
        } 
    }); 

    alert.show();
```

Answer (score 4):

This is the code on how to put seekbar in alertdialog:
check this [link](http://programondaspot.blogspot.com/2015/09/how-to-put-seek-bar-in-alert-dialog.html).

```
public void ShowDialog(){
 final AlertDialog.Builder popDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
 final SeekBar seek = new SeekBar(this);
 seek.setMax(255);
 seek.setKeyProgressIncrement(1);

 popDialog.setIcon(android.R.drawable.btn_star_big_on);
popDialog.setTitle("Please Select Into Your Desired Brightness ");
 popDialog.setView(seek);


   seek.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {



 public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser){


 txtView.setText("Value of : " + progress);
 }
```

HAPPY CODING!

Answer (score -1):

Create a view having edittext. use `setView()` method of AlertBuilder  to set the view.

### mytest.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/textview1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:hint="8+ characters"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:maxLength="18"
        android:imeOptions="actionSend|flagNoEnterAction" />

</RelativeLayout>



    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setView(entryView);
    builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
            .setCancelable(false)
           .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    MyActivity.this.finish();
           }
       })
       .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                dialog.cancel();
           }
       });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
```

Comment: Hmm.. so you mean i create an xml file for the dialog to view?